# T-Cobbler Plus for Pi Zero W?

Tags: hardware, pi-zero-w

I'm looking at getting a T-Cobbler Plus as shown [here.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2028) For my project I was thinking of using a Raspberry Pi Zero W, and my question is whether the T-Cobbler will work with the Zero W? The description says that it works for "Model Zero, A+, B+, Pi 2,Pi 3". I couldn't find any one product that included the Zero W. I'm thinking it'll work because it's got the same connectors as the Zero, but just want to be sure that it'll work before I buy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work

On the page you link to it actually says

> Designed for use with any 2x20 connector Raspberry Pi.

which also confirms it